# UnregisteredNodeException causing dataNode on slave to fail startup

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I've a Hadoop 2.5 cluster of two machines, on the slave one the data node is failing with an `UnregisteredNodeException`. Here is the master configuration:

```
master$ jps
5036 Jps
7145 DataNode
918 ResourceManager
7338 SecondaryNameNode
6986 NameNode
1105 NodeManager
```

For the slave

```
slave$ jps
15950 Jps
26650 NodeManager
```

Here is the full stack trace from the `hadoop-hadoop-datanode-slave.log`:

```
2014-10-23 19:43:46,895 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-8947225-127.0.1.1-1409591980216 (Datanode Uuid 5c9f00ab-1d75-4706-8ed8-bfb449174c9a) service to hadoop-server/192.168.2.72:8020 is shutting down
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.UnregisteredNodeException): Data node DatanodeRegistration(192.168.2.73, datanodeUuid=5c9f00ab-1d75-4706-8ed8-bfb449174c9a, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-55;cid=CID-ab378c59-62ed-44ff-8814-03b5b733b6fa;nsid=1290295317;c=0) is attempting to report storage ID 5c9f00ab-1d75-4706-8ed8-bfb449174c9a. Node 192.168.2.72:50010 is expected to serve this storage.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.getDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.processReport(BlockManager.java:1702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.blockReport(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.blockReport(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:28061)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.blockReport(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.blockReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.blockReport(DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.blockReport(BPServiceActor.java:476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.offerService(BPServiceActor.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:834)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I issue `hdfs dfsadmin -report` on any of the two machines I see the following:

```
14/10/31 10:48:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Configured Capacity: 12547440640 (11.69 GB)
Present Capacity: 4710391808 (4.39 GB)
DFS Remaining: 4504489984 (4.20 GB)
DFS Used: 205901824 (196.36 MB)
DFS Used%: 4.37%
Under replicated blocks: 4
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 192.168.2.72:50010 (hadoop-server)
Hostname: hadoop-server
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 12547440640 (11.69 GB)
DFS Used: 205901824 (196.36 MB)
Non DFS Used: 7837048832 (7.30 GB)
DFS Remaining: 4504489984 (4.20 GB)
DFS Used%: 1.64%
DFS Remaining%: 35.90%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Fri Oct 31 10:48:35 CET 2014
```

Also, I can see/monitor the slave machine from the Resource Manger Web UI, so what is causing this failure and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you SSH from master to slave without password? Have you tried (re)formatting the namenode from master? Is the slave configured correctly to connect to the master? Does HDFS work on the master? How about on the slave?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I can SSH from master to slave without password and vice versa. HDFS works in both machines, for instance when I issue `hdfs dfs -ls` I get the same result. Didn't try to (re) format namenode.

Comment: I don't understand how the HDFS can work on the slave - there is no datanode running. If you insert a file from master, I guess the slave doesn't see it? Try reformatting the namenode also.

Comment: I tried to insert a file from master with `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal sample.txt /tmp/sample.txt` and on slave I can see it with `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/`. Same thing, I can remove it from slave `hdfs dfs -rm /tmp/sample.txt` I see the changes from the master. But cannot see the Data Node with `jps`!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've actually duplicated a vm to create the slave machines which lead to a situation where all nodes had same UUID. So (as discussed [here](http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#post-1662788498)) I shutdown the services in the slave:

```
hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode
yarn-daemon.sh stop nodemanager
```

Then, I deleted the datanode and namenode directories (in `dfs.datanode.data.dir` and `dfs.namenode.data.dir` respectively). Then, restarted the datanode and namenode. Now I can see the datanode up and running:

```
$ jps
17135 NodeManager
17290 DataNode
18221 Jps
```